# Getting height of div when it does not have a specified class

Tags: javascript, html, css

building, and I ran into an issue in my javascript (plain javascript). I have an fixed nav bar that shrinks when the user scrolls down. I don't use sticky elements because they run into difficulties with certain computers. When the user scrolls down, this class is added to the nav bar.

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0),rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
```

Since this nav bar is never relative, I add a margin to the top of the second element in the body. Like this:

```
var mainNav = document.querySelector(".header-nav");
var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName('HEADER')[0];

tmp.nextElementSibling.style.marginTop = mainNav.offsetHeight + "px";

window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    tmp.nextElementSibling.style.marginTop = mainNav.offsetHeight + "px";
})
```

The issue I am running into deals with my resize function that I use because the header needs to change in height depending on browser size. Now if I resize the page at the top of the page, when the header is unshrunk (say 150px), everything works fine. But if I scroll to the middle of the page when the navbar is smaller, say 70 pixels tall, then when I scroll back up, the marginTop of the second element is only 70px versus the 150px I need it to be when the navbar grows again. Hope this makes my problem clear. I am wondering if there is a way to get mainNav.offsetHeight as a value like mainNav(without .sticky class).offsetHeight

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong with using `offsetHeight` just as you said?

Comment: Probably need a [example]

Answer (score 1):

From the question:

> I am wondering if there is a way to get `mainNav.offsetHeight` as a value like `mainNav(without .sticky class).offsetHeight`

The problem is how to determine both the default (no .sticky) and .sticky heights of the header.

Here's a trick to do that:

A. Clone the header and make the clone invisible,

B. Add cloned header after the real header,

C. Determine the default and `.sticky` heights of the cloned header,

D. Remove the cloned header from the DOM,

E. Return default and `.sticky` offset heights.

```js
function getHeaderHeights() {
  const hdr = document.querySelector('.header-nav');
  const hdrClone = hdr.cloneNode(true);
  hdrClone.style.opacity = 0;
  hdr.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', hdrClone);

  const defaultHeight = hdrClone.offsetHeight;

  hdrClone.classList.add('sticky');
  const stickyHeight = hdrClone.offsetHeight;
  hdrClone.remove();
  return {
    defaultHeight,
    stickyHeight
  };
}

const {
  defaultHeight,
  stickyHeight
} = getHeaderHeights();
console.log(`Header ht: ${defaultHeight}, stickyHt: ${stickyHeight}`);
```

```css
.header-nav {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  padding: 40px 5%;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<header class="header-nav">
  This is a sample header.<br> It has two lines of text.
</header>
```